# How to configure Crypto++ in Eclipse?

Tags: c++, crypto++

I want to use Crypto++ in Eclipse.
I've installed it correctly but I dunno why it cannot find the path.

```
using namespace CryptoPP;

Symbol CryptoPP cannot be resolved
```

and if I use #include "aes.h", for example is an unresolved inclusion.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Ok solved using this:
http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/tasks/cdt_t_proj_paths.htm

Just added the right path to configure cryptopp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the include paths for your project.

Assuming you are using CDT go to "Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings" and now in your configured compiler to "Includes" and add the path to your library. The same has to be done for your linker with "Libraries".