# Undefined reference to InvertibleRSAFunction and X509PublicKey using Crypto++?

Tags: c++, eclipse, crypto++

I'm trying to figure out how to generate and use an RSA key with Crypto++. To be precise, I am being asked to:

> 1. You will    implement   secure  communications  between two parties,    Alice   and 
>      Bob.
>      For   simplicity, the sending of  a   message from    the sender  to  the receiver    will    be  simulated
>      through   writing the message into    a   file    by  the sender  and reading the message
>      from  the file    by   the    receiver.
>      This  assignment  is  designed    to  practice    key distribution,   encryption/decryption,
>      and   integrity   protection
>      with  secret  key cryptography    and public  key cryptography.
> 2. Communication   scenario:   Alice (as   a   Client) needs   to  send    messages to Bob (as a   Server).    Alice    and    Bob each    have
>      a pair    of   under  the RSA cryptosystem
>      (their    key 
>      pairs are different), and they    know    each    other’s public  key beforehand
>      (the  public  keys    can be   hard   coded   into    the program
>      or    read    from    a   file). Step 1:  Set
>      up    a   shared  secret  key:    Alice   and Bob set up  a   shared  secret  key using   the following
>      method:   Alice   generates
>      a random  key k,  encrypts    it  using   Bob’s   public  key with    the RSA 
>      algorithm,    and sends   the ciphertext  to  Bob.    Bob receives    the ciphertext  and then    decrypts    it
>      to     get    the key k.

So, I've spent a few hours trying to set this up properly, and it seems like I've finally gotten Eclipse to accept the Crypto++ library itself, as it has compiled up to this point. Here is the complete code I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "cryptlib.h"
#include <rsa.h>
#include <osrng.h>
#include <base64.h>
#include <files.h>
using namespace CryptoPP;


int main()
{
    std::cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << std::endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!

     // InvertibleRSAFunction is used directly only because the private key
     // won't actually be used to perform any cryptographic operation;
     // otherwise, an appropriate typedef'ed type from rsa.h would have been used.
     AutoSeededRandomPool rng;
     InvertibleRSAFunction privkey;
     privkey.Initialize(rng, 1024);  <--

     // With the current version of Crypto++, MessageEnd() needs to be called
     // explicitly because Base64Encoder doesn't flush its buffer on destruction.
     Base64Encoder privkeysink(new FileSink("c:\\privkey.txt"));
     privkey.DEREncode(privkeysink);
     privkeysink.MessageEnd();

     // Suppose we want to store the public key separately,
     // possibly because we will be sending the public key to a third party.
     RSAFunction pubkey(privkey);

     Base64Encoder pubkeysink(new FileSink("c:\\pubkey.txt"));
     pubkey.DEREncode(pubkeysink); <--
     pubkeysink.MessageEnd();

    return 0;
}
```

Some of this I have pulled from here in an attempt to understand exactly how this library works:
https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/User_Guide:_rsa.h

(We were given no sort of primer, and I find the site a little confusing)

The current issue I'm having at the moment is that the two lines I've marked with '<--' do not compile.

Specifically:

```
undefined reference to CryptoPP::InvertibleRSAFunction::Initialize(CryptoPP::RandomNumberGenerator&, unsigned int, CryptoPP::Integer const&)

undefined reference to CryptoPP::X509PublicKey::DEREncode(CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation&) const
```

I would ask what I would need to do to make these two compile, but I'm not even sure this sample code even does what I want it to. How would I generate the keys I need for this?

Comment: Which version of Crypto++ are you using ?

Comment: @Blacktempel Crypto++ 7.0.0

Comment: Sounds like the code is compiling but not linking. Have you added crypto++ to your link command?

Comment: @Raznarok I have no problem compiling this code with v7.0.0. Have you tried compiling it with something else than Eclipse ? Also, how are you compiling Crypto++ ? As library, DLL, exe with your main... ?

Comment: @Blacktempel only Eclipse so far. I'm compiling crypto as a library.

Comment: I think @AlanBirtles is probably right. Also see [How to configure Crypto++ in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7847835/608639), [Adding standard libraries to C++ eclipse project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6869570/608639), [Cooperation between Eclipse and Crypto++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18968579/608639), [Configuring Eclipse to use Crypto++](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cryptopp-users/xct66aqkvfo/nvsy46qKzbcJ), etc.

Comment: Also see [RSA Cryptography](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RSA_Cryptography) and [RSA Encryption Schemes](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RSA_Encryption_Schemes) on the Cryto++ wiki. The User Guide you are using is a little old. It is from the Crypto++ 3.x and 4.x days.

Comment: @jww those last two you linked has one of code snippets I also tried.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: @Raznarok Please check the links jww has posted. Did you try these yet ? You will have to add the Crypto++ library to your linker.

Comment: @Blacktempel Linker?

Comment: @Raznarok Are you able to upload a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? Zip the project and upload it. You can do it without Crypto++, just preserve the paths.